# How do I access specific elements within a div tag using $(this)?

Tags: jquery

I've got some javascript that allows me to load states into a dropdown using json anytime the user changes the country.  This works great except that I can't have more than one of combination of country/state dropdowns on a page.  So, given HTML like the following:

```
<div id="div1" data-ajax-address="owner">
   <select id="country1" data-ajax-address="country"></select>
   <select id="state1" data-ajax-address="state"></select>
</div>
<div id="div2" data-ajax-address="owner">
    <p>
        <select id="country2" data-ajax-address="country"></select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <select id="state2" data-ajax-address="state"></select>
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$('div[data-ajax-address="owner"]').each(function() {
    $(this).children('select[data-ajax-address="country"]).change(function() {
        ....
    });
});
```

to access the country/state select elements within the div.  I can't use children() because they could be embedded within another element -- like the country2 & state2 being embedded inside of the paragraph tags.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$('div[data-ajax-address="owner"]').each(function() {
    $(this).find('select[data-ajax-address="country"]').change(function() {
        ....
    });
});
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a direct selection of the descendants if you want to:

```
    $('div[data-ajax-address="owner"] select[data-ajax-address="country"]').change(function() {...});
```

Shorter and same precision